# How can I use a query string in my crontab?

Tags: php, linux

I need to have a query string in my crontab but it isn't working. Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP on the command line doesn't take arguments like that.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

```
$ php file.php arg1 arg2
```

file.php

```
<?php
print_r($argv)
```

Comment: Thanks. Without spending a lot of time reading and hunting through the docs, can you please tell me what my options are? I have to have thing back up and runnuing in about 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you scragar! With the first example on that page: `parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);` I got the GET parameters that I needed.

Answer (score 5):

I just got it to work by wrapping the url in quotes:

```
47 17 * * * wget "http://example.com/dir/filename.php?l=ca&page=10"
```

Before adding the quotes, the file was able to GET 'l' but not 'page'.

Comment: Use `example.com` as sample domain names. Read the message at http://www.example.com/ to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

$ php example.php param1=value1 param2=value2

example.php:

```
<?php
echo "param1:" . $param1 . " ";
echo "param2:" . $param2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the example by @scragar, or you could alternatively run wget and then pipe the output to null.

Answer (score 0):

wget example:

$ wget http://your_host/example.php?param1=value1&param2=value2 2 > null